# Merging categorical vectors

Tags: r

Sorry this seems like a simple question, but I can't figure it out.

In R I have 3 categorical variables, and I want to merge them.

For example I want to take:

```
a <- c("a","b","c")
b <- c("d","e","f")
c <- c("g", "h", "i")
```

and turn it into:

```
x <- c("adg", "beh", "cfi")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` for this:

```
a <- c("a","b","c")
b <- c("d","e","f")
c <- c("g", "h", "i")
sprintf('%s%s%s', a, b, c)
```

or use `paste`:

```
paste(a, b, c, sep = '')
```

Comment: You can accept my answer as the correct by clicking on the green tick mark right next to my answer.